# app#get() not doing anything, (node.js + express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web

i recently today wanted to switch to express 4.x scince i've been working with 3.x a longer time than needed.

Basically i made a very simple application but the app#get() is not working at all!

this is my code:

```js
/** Declaring constants */
const config = require( "./config.json" );
const methods = require( "./depending_methods.js" );

const sessions = new Map( );

const express = require( "express" );
const path = require( "path" );
const bodyParser = require( "body-parser" );
const app = express();


let currentdata;

/**
 * some mongodb stuff ##redacted
 */

/** Configuration Express + HBS and Middleware */
    app.use(require('morgan')("dev"))
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(require( "cookie-parser" ));
    app.use(express.static('static'));
    app.use('./views', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './views')));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './views')));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

    require('hbs').registerHelper(require('handlebars-helpers')());


    console.log("registered get()")
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log("triggered /");
    res.send("Hey");
})


/** Configure port and start the Server! */
app.listen(config.port);
console.log("skynet is on: http://127.0.0.1:" + config.port + "/");
```

When i try to access 127.0.0.1:[port]/ or do a curl request:

The "triggered /" does not happen, but the "registered get()" at the start does.

I also get the obligatory "GET / - - ms - -" in the console

what did i do wrong?

Comment: @mmnjg123 don't you have to make a request to `http://localhost:[port]/` for you to see `triggered` on the console? So open a browser or use `curl` to go to the `URL` displayed on your console once the server is registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log("triggered /");
    res.send("Hey");
});
```

Means you have to make GET http request to [http://127.0.0.1:[whatever-port-you-use]/](http://127.0.0.1:%5Bwhatever-port-you-use%5D/) in order for callback function to fire; this being the `root` route represented by the `/` at the end of the URL.

**UPDATE**

Upon clarification and further scrutiny, the problem is with the line:

```
app.use(require( "cookie-parser" ));
```

The correct way to write it is:

```
app.use( (require( "cookie-parser" ))() );
//see (..) surrounding require and () after it
```

Alternatively, you can do it in two steps as shown on the [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) page:

```
const cookieParser = require( "cookie-parser" );
app.use( cookieParser() ); //NOT app.use( cookieParser );
```

**NOTE**

I would also advice that you go through the documentation for the other modules.

Comment: maybe i haven't made my point clear. I do this and nothing happens, and the request times out hence the: GET / - - ms - -

Comment: I gather you do not see `Hey` either (via http) ... please take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077355/what-does-get-bla-ms-mean-in-nodejs-console). As they say, morgan package prints "GET / - - ms - -" in the console. And the reason why you are not getting "triggered /" may probably be you or one of your packages forgot to call next().

Comment: If it's that similar to another question, please consider flagging the question as a duplicate. That helps consolidate questions and focus attention on individual answers.